# When is SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate's productViewControllerDidFinish: method called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have an application which uses SKStoreProductViewController to display an Appstore link within the app context. And I am now wondering when exactly is SKStoreProductViewControllerDelegate's productViewControllerDidFinish: method called?

I have implemented this method as follows:

```
- (void)productViewControllerDidFinish:(SKStoreProductViewController *)viewController {
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

When I have displayed the store within the app, and when

- "Cancel" button is clicked, SKStoreProductViewController is dismissed - which is expected.
- "Install" button is clicked, the user is authorized (if not already) and then, SKStoreProductViewController is dismissed - which is causing the confusion here. Is this dismissal expected?

References:

1) [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewControllerDelegate_ProtocolRef/Reference/Reference.html) says that:

> productViewControllerDidFinish:
>
> Called when the user dismisses the store screen. (required)

2) [This site](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios_6/changes_to_storekit) says that:

> This event is called when the user presses cancel; or otherwise finalizes a transaction inside the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is expected.

This method is just your way to know when you should close the store view and return to the app, either because the user finished the transaction or just cancelled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Hejazi. But a user might want to do different things other than just downloading the app, For example, he might also want to read reviews in the same SKStoreProductViewController. And if he ever wants to go back to the app, He always have the Cancel/Done button on the top left. I really don't understand why apple has to give this finish callback (dismissal) at the time when the app download starts..

Comment: In short, Do you know if there is a way to distinguish between the "Cancel" button click and the "Install" button click? As I do not want to dismiss the SKStoreProductViewController on "Install" button. I want it to show the download progress in the same view controller and "Install" button getting changed to "Open" button.. (appstore experience).

Comment: I agree with you, but existing public API treats both cases the same way. So you have no option here I think.

Comment: OK, thanks @Hejazi. I will wait for some time then I will mark this answer as correct :)